# Show that the ith power of the reversal of a string is the reversal of the ith power of the string

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I need to show that (w<sup>r</sup>)<sup>i</sup> = (w<sup>i</sup>)<sup>r</sup>

I'm trying to do this through inductions, so this is what I have so far:

Let P(w) be the statement: (w<sup>r</sup>)<sup>i</sup> = (w<sup>i</sup>)<sup>r</sup>

Basis: Prove P(λ) is true:
(λ<sup>r</sup>)<sup>i</sup> = (λ)<sup>i</sup> = λλ...λ = λ = (λ)<sup>r</sup> = (λ<sup>i</sup>)<sup>r</sup>

Inductive Hypothesis: Assume P(y) is true, where y is a string.

Inductive Step: Prove P(yx) is true where x is a character:
((yx)<sup>r</sup>)<sup>i</sup> = (xy<sup>r</sup>)<sup>i</sup> = ?

I have no clue how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Don’t induct on the construction of the word; induct on $i$ instead. Clearly for any word $w$ you have $(w^r)^1=w^r=(w^1)^r$. Now show that if $(w^r)^i=(w^i)^r$, then $(w^r)^{i+1}=(w^{i+1})^r$.

Comment: How do you determine which variable to induct on, generally?

Comment: @Rahat: Partly experience. Here both choices are reasonable possibilities, but induction on $i$ is likely to be more straightforward than the structural induction on $w$, if it works at all, so I’d probably have looked at it first. In this case I looked at the other first, since it was what you’d tried, and quickly determined that it would be messy if it worked at all, so I looked at induction on $i$ instead.